How did scholars of the past know the vacuous truth?
I know that vacuous truth is something that scholars have known implicitly since the past. However, in modern times, we can know that the vacuous truth is true through the truth table, but how could the vacuous truth be derived in the past? And I saw somewhere that the first time vacuous truth was briefly stated in the paper was when Russell wrote not A, then B. Is this correct?


Is it really true that Russell was the first to write about vacuous truth?
Also, is it true that the content was not A, then B?



The question is based on false premises.  Vacuous and trivial truth are two very basic logical notions, corresponding to the logical forms "false => anything" (vacuous truth: from contradictions) and "anything => true" (trivial truth: of tautologies).  And, while systematizing these may very well have had to wait for modern times, I am not in fact aware of any particular philosophical significance to these notions.

"Known implicitly" can mean a lot of things, especially when modern conceptions are read into the distant past. The term "vacuous truth" was not in use until 1940s, but one does not need truth tables to describe peculiarities of the material conditional, words suffice. Philo did it two millenia before Russell, c. 300 BC, as related by Sextus:"Philo says a conditional... is also true when it begins with a falsehood and ends with a falsehood, like "if the earth flies, the earth has wings"." Kneale, Development of Logic, p. 130.

The vacuous truth of a material conditional is related to the principle of explosion. That goes back at least to William of Soissons in the 12th century and was proved by using what we would now call disjunctive addition and disjunctive syllogism. See, e.g., this post.

Now we can try to answer...
Thanks to another post, we can find a clear understanding of the modern concept -if not the term- of vacuous truth into: Bertrand Russell, The Existential Import of Propositions (Mind, 1905):

Thus, if "XA = X" means "every X is an A," then
"0A = 0" means "every member of the class which has no
members is an A," or "for every value of x, 'x is a member of the
class which has no members' implies 'x is an A' ". This hypothetical [a conditonal statement] is true for all values of x, because its hypothesis [the antecedent] is false for all values of x, and a hypothetical with a false hypothesis is true.

Thus, the two key ingredients of vacuous truth (a general conditional holding vacuously) are already there:

the truth-functional analysis of the conditional connective (the hypothetical statement), and
the modern concept of empty class.

